# JavaScript/HTML to alternate row colors for input type textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

Is there an easy way to have an HTML `<textarea>` alternate its row colors 
to improve editing?

I don't mind if the solution is pure CSS or if it requires JavaScript.

Comment: Not a textarea, but maybe look into HTML5's ContentEditable attribute: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Answer (score 8):

```
textarea {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#F1F1F1 50%, #F9F9F9 50%);
  background-size: 100% 4rem;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  line-height: 2rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

Found this on codepen. Working for me.

Comment: add "background-attachment: local;" for textarea text to scroll with the background. WONDERFUL!!

Comment: Also, if you want to change the size of line-height, you also have to proportionally change the background-size. Also, move the textarea text up/down with the top padding. It's quirky to set it up but it's possible!

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly that you want the colors alternating WITHIN the textarea (as in each line)?

I would suggest the easiest method is to use a background image in your textarea's and have the rows of the alternate colors the same height as the font-size/line-height to create the illusion of alternate rows, then just repeat the background image.

**Additional Solution**

However, it seems that using that method, the background doesn't scroll along with each line.

The best technique I can come up with is to use a jQuery plugin called 'autoResize' by James Padolsey. What this does is removes the scrollbars and as your text nears the bottom of the `textarea`, the `textarea` height is increased accordingly.

Now, that can cause problems since you could potentially have VERY long textareas depending on how much text the user writes but I've created a fix for this.

What we can do is wrap the `textarea` in a `div` and set the `overflow-y` (vertical) to `scroll` and the `overflow-x` (horizontal) to `hidden`. What this does is now give us a "fake" scrollbar on our `textarea`, creating the illusion that it's scrollable so our background now appears as if it scrolls up and down with the text too.

You will have to adjust the width/height/margins/borders/paddings etc accordingly and maybe check for cross browser compatibility, but this should help set you on the right track and get you going.

Here is a link to an example I have created using the above method:

http://jsfiddle.net/HelloJoe/DmPLH/

Comment: Thanks really cool solution. I will tick it as best unless somebody suggests something without using an image.

Comment: This would work as long as your line-height/font variation matched the height of the background image coloured "rows"

Comment: this sounds like a good idea.. I dont think there is other simple way to do it in textarea

Comment: @HelloJoe that won't work. I have tried it. imagine your height is 14px. the image is 28px (red top orange bottom) the problem is that you assume that your text is always at the top of the text area which might not be. the text could be partly cut off, because of scrolling.

Comment: I see what you mean, I can help try and figure out an alternative solution unless you've already found a solution yourself?

Answer (score 2):

CSS supports an `nth child` syntax now. Check out the MDN docs for an example of changing the background-color of only every other list item inside an unordered list:

HTML:

```
<p>NBA players with most championships:</p>
<ul>
    <li>Bill Russell</li>
    <li>Sam Jones</li>
    <li>Tom Heinsohn</li>
    <li>K. C. Jones</li>
    <li>Satch Sanders</li>
    <li>John Havlicek</li>
    <li>Jim Loscutoff</li>
    <li>Frank Ramsey</li>
    <li>Robert Horry</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

RESULT:

[An example of making every other line in a textarea a different color by using CSS' nth-child syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDY3Y.png)

SOURCE:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child